# Using ExtJS along with the Rails Assets Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, asset-pipeline

For an application built on top of Rails (3.1.8) with ExtJS 4.1, we have the following files layout:

```
app/
  assets/
  javascript/
    application.coffee
    WID/
      Lots of coffeescript files and folders.
public/
  extjs/
    ext-all-debug-w-comments.js and the whole ExtJS framework.
```

Our application heavily relies on the Ext loader (Ext.Require) to dynamically load files based on users rights / allowed modules. We would like to keep this functionality as much as possible, so only the required files are requested from the server. Bandwidth isn't really an issue, as the application is intranet-based (On a LAN).

In development environment, everything runs smooth. In production environment however, we are having problems. It looks like either the "rake assets:precompile" task is concatenating all files into an application.js file, and then when accessing our application the Ext loader complains that it can't find individual files (Because assets/WID/.../file.js isn't being served by the rails server).

So right now, i'm not sure what would be the best move to take... Is there anyone able to help us with a successful Rails + ExtJS production setup taking the best from the assets pipeline?

Thank you,

Pierre.

Comment: Is this a diagram of development?

Comment: Yes, the files layout is from the development filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move your javascripts (and generally all the assets) from your `public` into `vendor/assets/javascripts` when you are in development environment. This way the asset-pipeline gets in charge.

EDIT: You may consider reverting your manifest file to `application.js`, not `application.coffee`. Generally it is a bad idea to rename these special files : `application.css` and `application.js` .In case you have some coffescript to add , just create a new file and place it in an asset directory.

Comment: Will coffeescript be correctly compiled if placed in vendor/?

Comment: Absolutely, `vendor/assets/` is one of the default [asset directories](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). The other two are `app/assets` and `lib/assets`.

Comment: i moved the files from the /app/assets/javascript folder to the /vendor/assets/javascripts. However, when accessing the application, the files still cannot be served. For instance, when trying to access a file located in "/vendor/assets/javascripts/WID/grinder/Core.coffee", the server answer is: "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/Wid/grinder/Core.js".

Comment: Can you post your `appliaction.js` file? I suggest you have to `//= require grinder` or `//= require_tree .` .

Comment: /app/assets/javascripts/application.coffee is reading:

#= require_tree .
#= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.

Now, the server is saying:

Started GET "/assets/application-241478e1c852cf05ebd511f7049f47b7.js" for xx.xx.xx.xx at 2013-02-21 11:49:57 +0000
  Processing by AssetsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"application-241478e1c852cf05ebd511f7049f47b7"}
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 0ms

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, the application logic is in "/vendor/assets/javascripts/main.coffee". The "/app/assets/javascripts/application.js" only contains the manifest lines as well as the application initialization code. However, when raking assets:precompile, all the assets required by the application are being precompiled into application-[hash].js file, and the app fails to start because objects are not defined the right way (With ExtJS, you mostly instanciate an object based it's name, then the Ext.Loader class handles loading the javascript file at the right URL, still fails now).

Comment: I would suggest to prefix the `main` file with `.js.coffee` , this is the way to compile from coffe to js using asset-pipeline. One more thing : it is not a good idea to `rake assets:precompile` in development mode, revert it by `rake assets:clean`.

Comment: The main.coffee file gets compiled into the application-[hash].js file, i have checked. Also, i have tried clearing the assets and restarting, it won't change a thing. Again, the problem is that all our custom Ext classes are being put in the application-[hash].js file, and we don't want that! Instead, we want the server to be able to serve individual files on-demand.